# Scala pattern matching always goes to default case

Tags: scala

First of all, I'm relatively new to scala.

Consider the following simple class NullLogService which logs results to console.

```
package services

import akka.actor._
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailResult
import model.Email

import scala.util.Try

object NullLogService {
  case class Log(email: Email, amazonResult: Try[_])
  case class LogError(email: Email, amazonException: Try[_])
}

class NullLogService  extends Actor {
  import NullLogService._

  def receive = {
    case Log(email, amazonResult) => println("Email to: " + email.to + ". AmazonResultSucess:" + amazonResult.isSuccess.toString + ". AmazonResult: " + amazonResult.get.toString)
    case LogError(email, amazonException) => println("Error: Email to: " + email.to + ". AmazonException:" + amazonException.get.toString)
    case default@_ => println("Default case: "+default.toString)
  }
}
```

It prints `Default case: Log(TO:email@email.com,Success({MessageId: Fake_Sent_OK}))` always.

I don't know what is happening, because the types are the same (Log(Email,Try(_))) ! It should go to the "Log" case but always fall to the default case!

Driving me crazy.

**Code involved**

Main class:

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Resume
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool
import akka.util.Timeout
import com.thenewmotion.akka.rabbitmq._
import com.typesafe.config.{ConfigFactory, ConfigParseOptions}
import model.Email
import services.EmailService.EmailInfo
import services.{EmailService, LogService, NullLogService}
import utils.StringUtils

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  val emailServiceRef: ActorRef = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(rate).withSupervisorStrategy(supervisorStrategy).props(Props(new EmailService)), "emailWorkerPool")
  val logServiceRef = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(1).props(Props(new NullLogService)), "logWorker")
  val email = new Email(stringMap.apply("USEREMAIL"), stringMap.apply("REPLYTO"), stringMap.apply("SUBJECT"), stringMap.apply("BODY"), unsubscribeURL)
  emailServiceRef ! EmailInfo(email, logServiceRef)
}
```

EmailService:

```
package services

import akka.actor._
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailResult
import model.Email
import services.LogService.{Log, LogError}

object EmailService {
  case class EmailInfo(email: Email, logServiceRef: ActorRef)
}

class EmailService extends Actor {
  import EmailService._

  def receive = {
    case EmailInfo(email, logServiceRef) =>    
      val emailResult = new SendRawEmailResult
      emailResult.setMessageId("Fake_Sent_OK" )
      val amazonResult = Try( emailResult )
      logServiceRef ! Log(email, amazonResult)
 }
}
```

Comment: It works well for me: `Email to: a@a.com. AmazonResultSucess:true. AmazonResult: email result`
The only thing I can think of is whether you are using the same class `NullLogService.Log` while sending message.

Comment: I have to agree with Jatin. It works well for me, too. Are you using an ActorSystem? Is there any other code involved?

Comment: I changed my NullLogService to print the default case. It prints `Log(TO:email@email.com,Success({MessageId: Fake_Sent_OK}))`. The case is "Log" and the types are Email. Also I changed the type to be "Try(_)" on the second parameter. Still not working. I don't know what else to do :C

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the code was ok guys. I found the problem: it was the import of the class NullLogService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you haven't removed `LogService.Log` and `LogService.LogError`, or else you would have gotten a compilation error for `EmailService`. In this case `NullLogService` shouldn't define its own messages, but use `LogService`'s ones:

```
package services

import akka.actor._
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailResult
import model.Email

import scala.util.Try
import LogService.{Log, LogError}

// no object NullLogService unless you need it for something else

class NullLogService extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Log(email, amazonResult) => println("Email to: " + email.to + ". AmazonResultSucess:" + amazonResult.isSuccess.toString + ". AmazonResult: " + amazonResult.get.toString)
    case LogError(email, amazonException) => println("Error: Email to: " + email.to + ". AmazonException:" + amazonException.get.toString)
    case default@_ => println("Default case: "+default.toString)
  }
}
```

Then you can switch between different services which use the same protocol (say, `NullLogService`, `Slf4jLogService`, `InMemoryLogService`) without changing the imports every time.

Comment: I was going to accept my answer, but to thank you for your suggestions I accept yours instead. Thank you. The code is cleaner now

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. I had to change the logger class I was importing.
I use NullLogService now, not LogService.

```
package services

import akka.actor._
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailResult
import model.Email
//Change this --> import services.LogService.{Log, LogError} <---
//To the class you are using --v
import services.NullLogService.{Log, LogError}


object EmailService {
  case class EmailInfo(email: Email, logServiceRef: ActorRef)
}

class EmailService extends Actor {
  import EmailService._

  def receive = {
    case EmailInfo(email, logServiceRef) =>    
      val emailResult = new SendRawEmailResult
      emailResult.setMessageId("Fake_Sent_OK" )
      val amazonResult = Try( emailResult )
      logServiceRef ! Log(email, amazonResult)
 }
}
```

It is weird because there was no runtime errors (like "NullLogService not imported")